# Convergence of a disjoint sets

Tags: general-topology, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose given a disjoint set:
$A_n = \{n\}$

The limit infimum clearly is an empty set since the set is disjoint. But, what about its limit supremum? Intuitively, the set is approaching infinity, but it seems rather weird. Does this mean the limit supremum diverge? Are there any other explanation?

Comment: Do you know the definition of $\limsup$ of sets?

Comment: I refer the definition from this article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit

Comment: So then you don't have to work intuitively, right? Get to use with the definition. You first need to compute a union and then an intersection. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: Your $C_n$ is correct. Now, you should want to show that $\bigcap_{n \ge 1} C_n = \varnothing$. This is simple if you know the definition of an arbitrary intersection. Namely, $x \in \bigcap_{n \ge 1} C_n$ iff $x \in C_n$ for all $n \ge 1$. 

Here, note that given any $k \in \Bbb N$, we have $k \notin C_{k + 1}$ and thus, the intersection has to be empty.

Comment: Ahh i didnt know the definition of arbitrary intersection.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intuition you have does not match the actual definition of the limit supremum of a sequence of sets. The definition is
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{m=n}^\infty A_n.
$$
Applying this to your situation yields
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \{n\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \{\underbrace{n,n+1,n+2,\dots}_{\text{all integers $\ge n$}.}\} = \varnothing,
$$
since no integer $k$ satisfies $k\ge n$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Another useful equivalent description of the limit supremum of a sequence of sets is
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n = \left\{ \, x\in\Omega \,\middle|\, \text{$x$ is contained in infinitely many of the $A_n$} \,\right\},
$$
where $\Omega$ is any common superset of all the $A_n$, for example $\Omega=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$. In your example, $\Omega$ could be $\mathbb N$ and no element $x\in\mathbb N$ is contained in infinitely many $\{n\}$.

Comment: Why is the intersection of the set is an empty set, isnt it supposed to be infinity since the upper bound is limitless??

Comment: Because no integer $k$ satisfies $k\ge n$ for all $n\ge 1$. "Infinity" is not an element of any of the $A_n$ and hence can't be an element of the limit supremum either.

Comment: Hmm i see. So, does this mean that this set converge to an empty set? Or does this set don't converge at all?

Comment: Since $\liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n=\varnothing$ as well, the set-theoretic limit exists and we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n = \varnothing$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand the concept much more clearly now.

Comment: You may want to accept this answer then so that your question is marked as answered.